# I have issue that my swiper does not show images

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-swiper

I am using react-native-swiper-flatlist.Swiper and dots from swiper are there but images are not showing. I am pretty new to react-native. This is my code:

```
<SwiperFlatList
          autoplay
          autoplayDelay={2}
          autoplayLoop
          index={2}
          showPagination
          data={img}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>{
            return(
              <Image style={{width, height: 200, backgroundColor:"#f0ffff" }} source={{uri:item.uri}}/>
            )
          } }
        />
```

Comment: what is width and is your data img is correct? check [this](https://snack.expo.io/@avhishekydv/smart-fudge) Its working

Comment: Issue seems to be with the source image image you are using. Check with smaller dimension first maybe 100*100.

Comment: here width is the width of the screen which i get from const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

Comment: i have checked with smaller dimensions it is still not showing

Comment: Can you please also specify how data would be provided to the swiper list I mean to say can you provide the data array format you are specifying to the swiper list with an example of data with actual values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First try to keep your SwiperFlatList inside View Component & Style Should be flex:1.
- Double check what is your Data format & how you render inside Image.

Otherwise Please Share Full Source Code.

Your image data is not from the web, this is local data so use this code :

```
<Image style={{width, height: 300, backgroundColor:"#f0ffff",flex: 1 }} source={item.uri}/>
```

instead of

```
<Image style={{width, height: 300, backgroundColor:"#f0ffff",flex: 1 }} source={{uri:item.uri}}/>
```

also change data formate :

```
const img=[
    {uri:'../../assets/image.png', key: '1'},
    {uri:'../../assets/image.png', key: '2'},
    {uri:'../../assets/image.png', key: '3'}
  ];
```

to

```
const img=[
    {uri:require('../../assets/image.png'), key: '1'},
    {uri:require('../../assets/image.png'), key: '2'},
    {uri:require('../../assets/image.png'), key: '3'}
  ];
```

Comment: https://github.com/raj-bhagat/stackoverflow/blob/main/HomeScreen.js This is the link to the code

Comment: Your image data is not from the web, this is local data so use this code :
<Image style={{width, height: 300, backgroundColor:"#f0ffff",flex: 1 }} source={item.uri}/>

instead of

<Image style={{width, height: 300, backgroundColor:"#f0ffff",flex: 1 }} source={{uri:item.uri}}/>

Comment: also change data formate :
const img=[
    {uri:'../../assets/image.png', key: '1'},
    {uri:'../../assets/image.png', key: '2'},
    {uri:'../../assets/image.png', key: '3'}
  ];

to 

const img=[
    {uri:require('../../assets/image.png'), key: '1'},
    {uri:require('../../assets/image.png'), key: '2'},
    {uri:require('../../assets/image.png'), key: '3'}
  ];

Comment: Thank you the image is loaded now i just need to align it.

Comment: Show me a ScreenShot & What align You want? (Horizontal or Vertical)